# Is this shader can exist in Unity?

Tags: unity, shaders

[image]

'Front' and 'back' are all SpriteRenderer.

Do you have a Shader these things that will be present in the Unity?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. Do you want a shader which inverts the Z-buffer? Or do you want certain things to be always rendered in front of certain other things? When it's the latter, you can do that with multiple cameras with different culling masks.

Comment: i just want to know is it possible in shader. and multiple camera way can't not help to me.

Comment: You still haven't said what *exactly* you want to do.

Comment: This question is extremely unclear.  If you are asking if there is a built in shader to set the drawing order in Unity, no there is not.  Voting to hold question.  Fix.

Comment: You'd need to change depth-test-settings, no clue if this is possible in unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need a shader for this. Setting the Order in Layer of the Back sprite render toa higher value that the Order in Layer of the Fron sprite renderer makes sure that Back renders in front of Front in 2d space, regardless of the position in 3d space.

Comment: i know that. but i'm in special situalation so i need to solve it through a shader unfortunately

Comment: @mjk6026 Then you need to clarify why you need a shader to do this in your question